# The set of open ball of radius strictly greater than 1 is not a basis of a topology

Tags: general-topology

I am asked the following question:

> Let $X$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Does the set $\mathcal{B}_{>}=\left\{ B_{\varepsilon}(x) : \varepsilon>1,x\in X\right\}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$ if we consider the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

It is clear that $\mathcal{B}_{>}$ is not a basis, by using the following counter-example:

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$. On the real line, an open ball is by definition an open interval. Consider $x_{1}=0$ and $x_{2}=2$. Then, let $\varepsilon=3/2>1$. So, we can pick the two following open ball centered at $x_{i}$ with radius $3/2$, i.e $0\in B_{3/2}(0)=(-3/2,3/2)\in\mathcal{B}_{>}$ and $2\in B_{3/2}(2)=(1/2,7/2)\in\mathcal{B}_{>}$.

If $\mathcal{B}_{>}$ was indeed a basis, then we could find for every $x\in B_{3/2}(0)\cap B_{3/2}(2)$ an element $B\in\mathcal{B}_{>}$ such that $x\in B \subseteq B_{3/2}(0)\cap B_{3/2}(2)$. But, since $1\in B_{3/2}(0)\cap B_{3/2}(2)=(1/2,3/2)$, it is clear that we can not find an $\varepsilon>1$ that would work, since $d(1,3/2)=d(1,1/2)=1/2<1$.

So, $\mathcal{B}_{>}$ is not a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is the following: how would one prove it without the use of a counter-example? I've tried proving it using a contradiction, but without any luck. I considered two open ball of radius $>1$ centered on two points, such that their intersection is not empty. Since it is not empty, there must be atleast a point inside it, let's call it $z$. I then supposed that an $\varepsilon>1$ existed such that $B_{\varepsilon}(z)$ is a subset of the intersection. But then, I can not show any contradiction.

Any help on a formal proof would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: By “$X$ is any set” do they mean “$X$ is any metric space”? Or are we assuming everything under consideration is a subset/subspace of $\mathbb R$ (Or $\mathbb R^n$)?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I assume they mean that $X$ is a metric space, since we are considering open balls.

Comment: In that case, it’s possible it is a base, say if the metric is discrete with the distance between distinct points greater than $2$. (But also possible it isn’t as your example shows.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, I can see why it is indeed a base by using your example. I assume then that $X$ must be a sub(set/space) of $\mathbb{R}$ since the answer I have for this question is that the set is not a basis. I'll edit my post, since I'm still curious about a formal proof if the metric is the usual one.